# How to ask another person’s cell number?

Tags: difference, word-choice, single-word-request

How do you ask when you want to know any third persons cell number?
e.g.:

> A: Du hast mich angerufen, aber wie weißt du, was meine Handynummer ist?
>   B: Ich habe sie von Daniel gelernt/erfahren/erhalten

Is this conversation possible?

Comment: Hi and welcome to German Language Stack Exchange. Feel free to take a [tour] of the site and visit the [help] to learn all about it. Unfortunately, simple single-word translation requests are off-topic here. Did you attempt to look up possible words in a dictionary? If so, do you have an assumption which ones work better than others and why? I would recommend you added that to your question, otherwise it might get closed for simple translation requesting.

Comment: thanks for welcoming and being accepted to the community, i just would like to know, if we can say: "ich habe sie von Daniel gelernt?

Comment: *Gelernt* is not a good choice, since it implies *learning* in the traditional sense. *Erfahren* or *erhalten* are better coices.

Comment: i think "wir lernen nur nützliche Informationen" like geo, math etc. what is the field that " lernen" could be not used or could be used? what can one learn or what can not learn?

Comment: When (not) to use _lernen_ could be a separate question. My short take on it: _lernen_ is used when there is some mental work involved that goes beyond hearing and noting simple facts like phone numbers.

Answer (score 3):

You would ask *woher?* or *von wem?*, und you could use *haben* in place of *wissen*:

> ... aber [woher | von wem] [weißt | hast] du meine Handynummer?

For the answer, actually the best choice would be to omit the verb:

> Ich habe sie von Daniel.

If you want to have a verb in it, than use *bekommen*. You could also rephrase it this way:

> Daniel hat sie mir gegeben.

Comment: "ich habe deine Handynummer von Daniel, und wollte ich dich am Wochende zweimal anrufen, aber du hast nicht beantwortet" is this konstruction grammatically and in meaning correct,and could you please say how to say when another person on the line,do you say: Telephon ist besetzt oder beschäftigt?

Comment: @Bergmann "ich wollte" and "**g**eantwortet", otherwise correct; "Das Tele**f**on ist besetzt.", but please avoid asking new questions in comments.

Comment: do i need to create new titel instead then?

Comment: Why do you ignore *erhalten* and *erfahren*?

Comment: @Bergmann Yes, new question should *always* be with *Ask question* up on the top. But beware that some questions might be deemed to trivial and would be better asked in the [chat] (once you have 20 rep).

Comment: @CarstenS Because I consider _bekommen_ the best option, and I was too tired for a full-length discussion in my answer. IMHO both are valid alternatives, though a _little_ bit too elevated for that informal, colloquial conversation. In addition, _erfahren_ sounds (to me) like it wasn't 100% trivial to get that number, like _in Erfahrung bringen_.

Comment: @Matthias, meine Kritik wäre gewesen, dass Du damit die Frage ignoriert hast, aber dann habe ich gesehen, dass die Frage ohnehin nur nach A war, also was soll's. Was die Sprachebenen angeht, gebe ich Dir recht.

Comment: Also, _kennen_ is more appropriate than _wissen_ here. Depending on intention or level of surprise, one could also ask with _wieso_ or _warum_ ‘why?’ instead of _woher_.